# Reliability issues with si5351 when generating two clocks with a phase difference of 90 degree

Tags: i2c, clock, clock-speed, phase-shift, si5351

I am trying to generate two clocks of X-MHz each, X being a value ranging from 5 to 100. I chose si5351 chip for this as a breakout board was easily available from Adafruit. I used attached code to generate clocks from CLK0 and CLK1 outputs with same frequency but 90 degree phase difference.

main.c

```
void init()
{
const int32_t correction = 978;

si5351_Init(correction);
si5351_SetupCLK0(5000000, SI5351_DRIVE_STRENGTH_4MA);
si5351_SetupCLK1(5000000, SI5351_DRIVE_STRENGTH_4MA);
si5351_EnableOutputs((1<<0) | (1<<1));
}


// main is called after all the nrf52832 startup code is executed
int main( void )
{

init();
return 0;
}
```

si5351 I2C driver I used was from github [I2C Driver](https://github.com/afiskon/stm32-si5351/tree/main/si5351).

I added following code in the si5351.c file to generate CLK1 output at 90 degree offset.

```
void si5351_SetupCLK1(int32_t Fclk, si5351DriveStrength_t driveStrength) {
si5351PLLConfig_t pll_conf;
si5351OutputConfig_t out_conf;

si5351_Calc(Fclk, &pll_conf, &out_conf);
si5351_SetupPLL(SI5351_PLL_A, &pll_conf);
si5351_SetupOutput(1, SI5351_PLL_A, driveStrength, &out_conf, 50);
}
```

I am using nrf52832 dev board to drive I2C over which the si5351 breakout board is connected. nrf52832 board also powers the si5351 breakout board. Now when I measure the outputs on oscilloscope every time I restart the system, phase offset between two clocks is always different. I have no idea why si5351 generates clocks with different phase each time I power on the whole system, while the code on nrf52832 is same.

Attached are the snapshots taken after a reset of the system where the phase applied on two clocks was 90 degree.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone point me if si5351 has reliability issues or I am doing any steps wrong here. Please note that correction value for si5351 is taken as it is from github code.

Comment: A quote from a Si5351 guru Hans Summers: *If you don't do a PLL reset under these two circumstances then the phase offset will be random*. These two conditions are:(1) A change to **Multisynth divider** registers (as distinct from **PLL feedback divider**); (2) whenever you switch outputs on/off using **Clock_Control_registers** like register 16 The original SiLabs documentation is a bit sketchy, and is misleading in places. We should not be too upset - documenting the dependencies of nearly 200 registers is daunting.

Comment: FIY see also [this discussion](https://groups.io/g/QRPLabs/topic/si5351a_phase_offset_step/6380865) eg: "Two Si5351A outputs CAN be configured with 90-degree phase offset down to 3.2MHz" so perhaps the available phase offset register is too small at your lowest frequencies?